# Druid with Kafka Ingestion: filtering data

Tags: apache-kafka, druid, data-ingestion

is it possible to filter data by dimension value during ingestion from Kafka to Druid?

e.g. Considering dimension: `version`, which might have values: `v1`, `v2`, `v3` I would like to have only `v2` loaded.

I realize it can be done using Spark/Flink/Kafka Streams, but maybe there is an out-of-the-box solution

Comment: I need this feature, too, but I've seen a few times that Druid people mentioned the ETL is not the scope of Druid.  I think it's difficult to implement a general purpose ETL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `transformSpec` during ingestion.
http://druid.io/docs/latest/ingestion/transform-spec.html

Per the documentation:

> Transform specs allow Druid to filter and transform input data during
>   ingestion.

Any [query filters](http://druid.io/docs/latest/querying/filters.html) can be applied to this.

Example usage with `NOT` filter:

```
"transformSpec": {
  "filter": {
    "type": "and",
    "fields": [
      {
        "type": "not",
        "field": {
          "type": "selector",
          "dimension": "my_dimension",
          "value": "filter_me"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "not",
        "field": {
          "type": "selector",
          "dimension": "my_dimension",
          "value": "filter_me_also"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "transforms": []
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not possible from druid side you need to filter the data before hand.

Comment: Outdated answer.

Comment: I also tried native batch ingestion with task (firehose). its actually reindexing existing segments with filters. but didn't work with filters in tansformSpec.